# Umbraco 7 if File Upload is empty

Tags: c#, umbraco7

I'm using Umbraco 7 with a File Upload. I would like to check IF there is or isn't a file uploaded.

If there isn't a file uploaded, I recieve the following error: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I have removed some code to make it easier to read through, but below is my surfacecontroller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web;

namespace Sp34k.Controllers
{
    public class GalleryItem
    {
        public string projectFile { get; set; }
    }

    public class PortfolioSurfaceController : SurfaceController
    {
        // GET: PortfolioSurface
        public ActionResult GetCategoryDetails(int id)
        {
            GalleryItem gItem = new GalleryItem();
            var node = Umbraco.TypedContent(id);

            string file = node["uploadProjectFiles"].ToString();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
            {
                gItem.projectFile = node["uploadProjectFiles"].ToString();
            }

            return Json(gItem, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worst. Headline. Ever. ;-)

Comment: Maybe it's better now? ;) I have no other clue how to explain it.

Comment: Yeah, this is much better. The first one I was like "what, String.IsNullOrEmpty()?" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is on this line:

```
string file = node["uploadProjectFiles"].ToString();
```

You may get a `null` as response to this from `node` with that key and you cannot call `ToString()` on it.

There is also another issue: if the string *is* null or whitespace you assign it to `gItem.projectFile`. I would assume you only want to assign it if it is *not* null or whitespace.

If the object in `node` is definitely a string or null, you can fix the code easily:

```
string file = node["uploadProjectFiles"] as string;

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
{
    gItem.projectFile = file;
}
```

The `as string` means "if the object is a string assign it as such, or if it isn't return null." This way you either get a string (might still be empty/whitespace) or null with the type string and you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

The node key which you are accessing is null probably, you need to check for null on it as well:

```
string file = node["uploadProjectFiles"] !=null ? node["uploadProjectFiles"].ToString() : String.Empty;
```

and then next use file variable:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file))
{
   gItem.projectFile = file;
}
```